# Arrow keys stop working when using less in a gnu screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

Sometimes when I am using `less` within a `screen` tab, the arrow keys display `^[OA`, `^[OB`, `^[OC`, and `^[OD` instead of doing what I want them to do.  Is there something I can do to fix this and gain control of `less` again?

Comment: For cmder and conemu, the solution is to add `-new_console:p5`. Source: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1832#issuecomment-649055755 - more discussion at https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1622

Answer (score 9):

enter `!reset` at the less prompt

Answer (score 4):

I have found that `reset` from *within* screen does not solve the problem sometimes, as it's the *outer* client/shell whose state is actually confused and screen captures the control characters from `reset` and prevents them from reaching the outer client.  In this situation, I have to detach my session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>), run `reset`, then attach to the session again (`screen -r`).

Answer (score 2):

- If it happens from time to time, it seems, that some application (e.g. `cat` or `less` a binary file) shatters your console by sending it [control characters](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-8.html#ss8.3). You need to run `reset` command from command line to recover.
- Otherwise you have to trick your terminal application. I suggest you to use [CryptoTerm](http://www.cryptoterm.com/) which allows you to define custom key mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is your TERM variable. In my case I ssh into a Linux box and run less inside screen - the TERM variable was set to 'screen' - which breaks arrow keys. It works perfectly if I run less this way:

```
TERM=xterm less <file>
```